# Tomcat can't find nocache.js 404 not found

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

I am pretty much a GWT newbie and have some issues with my Tomcat.
I'm running a local Tomcat on Windows with my GWT servlet deployed on it, but when I access it, my browser debugger says he can't find the `nocache.js`, even though he looks at the correct path. The error says:

> GET http://localhost:8080/homepage/homepage.nocache.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 10ms]

Which is just, where my `homepage.nocache.js` is. It may be some simple configuration problem, can someone help me please?

Comment: Is the file there when you visit http://localhost:8080/homepage/homepage.nocache.js in browser? What are the contents of the war-file (or your exploded webapp). Also is "homepage" is the correct gwt.xml module name? Could happen due rename

Comment: I just checked it out, it is not available from browser. In my war-file is my .html, .css the WEB-INF folder and the folder named homepage with all the compiled gwt stuff. 
homepage is the name of the servlet in the web.xml, is there some other location where I have to name it?

Comment: You have to compile your GWT application before you create and deploy the war-file.

Comment: Your servlet will be responsible for the client-server communication, but currently you're experiencing another issue: the static js-file, compile output of gwt:compile is missing. Did you execute gwt:compile before building war? Can you show us your pom file?

Comment: I did compile it, but not using maven or gradle, just the gwt compile supported by the gwt plugin for eclipse

Comment: Do you deploy the app in the /homepage/ context ? Please try to visit http://localhost:8080/homepage.nocache.js in your browser. Is it there?

Comment: Yes it is deployed under the /homepage/ context, but no it is not available from browser.

Comment: I think i got the source of the problem. I get the file if I start my browser with administrator rights, so it is a Windows problem. I will try to set up a new Tomcat. Thank you for your help :-)